# How to improve selection descendant speed in sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I need select all children (Descendants) items filtered by template id, under some specific item.
I can do it in a 3 way:

1. use GetDescendants `myitem.Axes.GetDescendants().Where(x => x.IsOfTemplate(MyItem.TemplateId)).Select(x => (MyItem)x).ToList();`
2. use xPath

   ```
    string q = string.Format("{0}//*[@@templateid='{1}']", myItem.Paths.Path, MyItem.TemplateId);
               var result = myItem.Database.SelectItems(q);
   ```
3. use Sitecore Search API

I can't use #3 for my case. Let skip it for my case.

Xpath selector #2 should work faster then #1, but problem is in a first call to some path.

By some reason first call to content tree with some specific path is very slow.
After this first call similar calls works very fast, it is doesn't matter witch style to use #1 or #2. Sitecore add some cache.

How to improve speed for first call ?

Comment: How many items are in your "path"? An option could be to use a "fast query" but that might not be the best solution. Normally the answer to this question would be #3.. why is that not possible?

Comment: Use the LinkDatabase. Find all items of templatetype XXX, for each item check .IsDescendantOf(yourRoot).

More here: http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2016/05/effective-use-of-sitecore-linkdatabase.html

Comment: Will end up being 100-200 times faster than the query approach.

Comment: Personally I've not found sitecore to scale particuarly well, regardless of data access, etc. If you need speed and large amounts of data roll your own cache. Maybe something like elastic search, redis cache layer on top of sitecore, [similar to how SO works](http://stackexchange.com/performance). I pretty much use SC as a datalayer only now.

Comment: Hey @Arbejdsglæde, consider marking Richard's answer as accepted in case it helped you.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko it is my answer as well. )))

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde is there a reason why you think there can be a better answer than what Richard has written?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I asked why first call is slow, I know that Search API is fast.

Comment: Your first call is slow because you are querying too much data through the api - a process that will never be fast unless cached - which is why your next queries are fast(er).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there are many ways to retrieve items (using the link databse as Mark Cassidy has suggested, using Siteocre Search API etc.) your issue is with your cache. If the query runs quick enough the second time around but slowly the first time then it's likely that some part of your cache is being emptied and then refilled. This is most likely to be one of the following: SqlDataProvider - Prefetch data 
master|web [data]
master|web [itempaths]
master|web [items]
master|web [paths]

To investigate this, use the admin cache page at /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx and pay particular attention not just to cache size, but to the delta (change in cache size) for caches that might be affected. If the delta  has negative values then your cache is being flushed to make room for newer data. You would need to look at increasing the size of that cache.

Please also bear in mind that caching should be configured for the particular environment a Sitecore instance is running in, and that e.g. recycling the application pool will flush your cache. If it's essential that your query runs quickly right from the start, then you could consider adding specific items to your prefetch cache. Adding items to the prefetch cache on application startup has a cost in startup time.

Please also remember that cache configuration should be the last resort when looking at slow running code - it merely treats the symptoms and not the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *always* #3 - by its very nature a Descendant walk is going to be a slow operation. Especially if you have a lot of descendants of your starting item.

The Sitecore Search API uses either Lucene or SOLR indexes that can search through thousands/millions of records very very quickly. The name makes it look like it should be used just for site searches, but in reality it should be used for most operations where you might use a Sitecore Query or XPath.

I'm not sure why you don't have that as an option. But you will struggle to speed up a descendants tree walk. Your only option to do that would be to restructure your content tree so the walk is not required.

Comment: #3 will expose your site to index corruption, which means stale results (old values), missing results (new items not appearing), lingering results (deleted/unpublished items remaining).
You can rebuild the index but there are no search results at all while rebuild is running.